# google+ google-api-java-client: getting person information about view count

Tags: java, google-plus, google-api-java-client

I'm discovering the google-api-java-client (google+) for java and for me it isn't clear how to get the total view count for any g+ profile.

In detail, I can get those properties outa Person model:
...

```
Person.getAboutMe()
Person.getPlusOneCount()
Person.getCircledByCount()
```

...
and lot's more but none with

```
getViewCount()
```

or something. Does anybody have a clue?

[circlecount.com](http://www.circlecount.com/p/+adidas?) is also able to get information about the view count, but how?

Thanks for any help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't currently exposed in the API, there is an open feature request for it here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=798

Circlecount uses page scraping to get some of the information that isn't available via the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to see the View count of someones Google+ profile though the API. A feature request has been made feel free to add your name to it. ["views" in people.get response](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=798) the more people that request it the better the chance we will have of them adding it.